# When user presses the Enter key, program loops back to start

Tags: string, python-3.x, int

I'm trying to make a program for my assignment and I have a question for a certain section.

One part of the program asks the user to input the first coin and if the user hits the ENTER key, then it should reiterate the program to ask the user to input the first coin again until they actually enter a number.

The code I have right now for this section is:

```
coin = int(input("Enter first coin: ))
    while coin == "": 
        coin = int(input("Enter first coin: ))
```

I know that the problem here is that I'm trying to take the empty string as an int which would create an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
builtins.ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

So my question is, how would I change my program so that the empty string can be changed to an int? I tried searching it all over the internet but I can't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use an infinite loop you can break out of and catch the exception

```
while True:
   try:
       coin = int(input("Enter coin: "))
       break
   except ValueError:
       continue
```

When they don't enter a real value the exception will be caught and then go through the loop again.  If they enter a real number you'll break out of the loop